# New to Python - super simple stuff! (Reading lists etc)

Tags: arrays, list, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Python, I want to make a program that asks the user for 3 letters and a string. Then it will print out all the letters of the string that start out with the three letters...e.g

```
Three letters: ABC
Text: A beautiful caterpillar crossed the great bridge owned by anthony bishop canister
A beautiful caterpillar
anthony bishop canister
```

My code is currently...

```
ipt1 = raw_input("Three letters: ") ## Asks for three letters
ipt2 = raw_input("Text: ") ## Asks for text
ipt1_split = ipt1.split() ## Converts three letters to list
ipt2_split = ipt2.split() ## Converts text to list
```

I don't know what to do after this, I'm not really sure if this is possible using python, if someone could complete the code for me it would be great, I'm thinking something along the lines of making a foor loop that scans the text and not really sure what to do after. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is using Python, by the way.

I'm writing a book and this would be helpful during the process for particular reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over all words, then over all letters and then check if the word begins with the letter, as follows:

```
ipt1 = raw_input("Three letters: ") ## Asks for three letters
ipt2 = raw_input("Text: ") ## Asks for text
ipt1_split = ipt1.split() ## Converts three letters to list
ipt2_split = ipt2.split() ## Converts text to list

for word in ipt2_split:
    for letter in ipt1_split:
        if word.startswith(letter):
            print word
```

Comment: Hmm. That returns a syntax error. My original code contained a few bugs, I edited it abit. Your reply was helpful nonetheless. If you could fix it, it would be great.